# MVC app getting stuck on an error after server restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies, simplemembership

The scenario is as follows. I start an instance of MVC app to debug it. The app uses simple membership and I log in during this run. Then I go back to VS change something and start the instance again. It doesn't happen really often but sometimes at this moment membership starts acting odd. As the app starts, some action, that is behind `[Authorize]` attribute (to be exact the attribute is on the controller), is called. However the action fails because `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` is equal -1 (the action in question just loads some user information based on `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`).

If I clear cookies in browser, everything is fine, but I can't expect users to do the same when they encounter the problem.

My colleague explaind to me that it's (probably) happening because my local IIS decided to restart and some of session cookies became invalid, but if this can happen on local instance of IIS, wouldn't it be possible to also happen on the remote server?

Other important fact, the action that fails is called (more like redirected to) by a custom filter that we wrote. This filter is applied to all actions (but doesn't affect the one mentioned). Can this filter somehow make MVC ignore `[Authorize]` attribute?

I have a dirty workaround for this problem that should work (with this specific app), but I would prefer to prevent the problem from appearing int the first place.

---

I think this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13850861). Basically when the server gets reset authentication cookies die. They get recreated right away, except my app doesn't really have access to them till the page is reloaded (just like with logging in).

I partially solved the problem described above (a redirect is preformed somewhere on the way) so the application no longer gets stuck. However, if someone was logged in during the time the server restarted and he tries to preform a post after that, his post will not work and he will be redirected to a get action with the same name as the post action (our custom filter is to blame for that). Unfortunately I cannot fix the filter, because I would need user id for that and at the point at which the filter is called, it's still -1.

Comment: why session data has anything to do with Authorize? In the life of ASP.NET Request, authorisation happens before session_start.

Comment: @Larry From what I understand user data (such as WebSecurity.CurrentUserId) lives in session data. My problem is, user stays authorized after the restart, but I can't even get his id (it equals -1), the application just crashes and keeps doing so untill I clear all cookies for the site in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my question is not too well written and kind of very localized (I should probably rewrite it or reask it), but the underlaying problem is more general than it seems, so let me salvage all the useful information into this answer.

Question 1: There is nothing preventing IIS from having a hiccup on a remote server and restarting the app, so yes this can (and happens) on the remote server (frequency will depend on the app itself and IIS configuration). The problem of disappearing session data seems to be related to the restarts of the app pool rather than the app itself.

Question 2: The custom filter has little to do with the situation. As pointed by Larry, in simple membership authorization is kind of unrelated to session data. If your session data is lost, the user does not stop being authorized, however user data is stored in the session. Without session you don't know who the user is. This information becomes available one action after session data was lost. So loosing session data can lead to a crash of the application or like in my case (where a custom filter depends on user data) to even weirder results.

So if you encounter unexpected disappearance of user data in your app (such as `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` becoming -1), it might be worth investigating if your app pool is getting restarted (and why). Setting memory limits for an app pool seems to increase the likelihood of those restarts.